# Convert product of Bessel functions of the first and second kind into a Meijer G-function

Tags: special-functions, bessel-functions

There exists such an equality which converts the product of Bessel functions of the first and second kind into a Meijer G-funtion, 
$$x^\mu J_\nu(x)Y_\nu(x)=-\pi^{-1/2}G_{13}^{20}\left(x^2\left| \begin{matrix}(1+\mu)/2\\ \mu/2+\nu, \mu/2,\mu/2-\nu\end{matrix}\right. \right) $$
which is equation (60) in page 220 in book, Higer transcendental functions [1]. However, there was no proof in this book.

Could anyone offer me a proof? A further question is: can we convert $\frac{\sin(t)Y_0(t)}{t}$ into a certain Meijer G-function? Thanks a lot.

[1] Bateman H, Erdelyi A (1953). Higher transcendental functions [M]. McGraw-Hill; New York.

Comment: $$\frac {Y_0(x) \sin x} x =
\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} G_{3, 5}^{2, 2} \left( x^2 \middle|
 {-\frac 1 4, \frac 1 4, -\frac 1 2 \atop
  0, 0, -\frac 1 2, -\frac 1 2, - \frac 1 2} \right).$$
Note that the rhs is an even function of $x$; neither formula holds for $\operatorname{Re} x < 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you show me how to get the equation for $\frac{Y_0(x)\sin(x)}{x}$? How about $ \frac{Y_0(x)(1-\cos(x))}{x}$? Or even more complicate case: can the functions $\frac{J_\mu(x) J_\nu(x)(1-\cos(x))}{x}$ and $\frac{J_\mu(x)J_\nu\sin(x)}{x}$ be converted to the Meijer G-function?

Comment: $Y_0(x) \sin x$ is [this formula](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselY/26/02/03/) with $\nu = 0$. Multiplication by $(x^2)^{-1/2}$ shifts all coefficients by $-1/2$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for bringing the formula for me. Where can I find the proof for this formula?

Comment: I don't know. For $J_\nu(x) Y_\nu(x)$ (you need only the case $\mu = 0$), a standard method is to write the G-function as its defining integral and evaluate it as a sum of residues. You get a sum of two ${_1F_2}$ terms. $Y_0(x) \sin x$ seems more difficult because you would have to compute residues at double poles.