# Proof of converting the product of Bessel function of the second kind and the sine function into Meijer $G$-function.

Tags: special-functions

How can I derive [the formula](http://functions.wolfram.com/Bessel-TypeFunctions/BesselY/26/02/03/) which converts the product of Bessel function of the second kind and the sine function into Meijer $G$-function,

> $$
> \sin(\sqrt{z})Y_v(\sqrt{z})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}G_{3,5}^{2,2} \left( z\left| \begin{matrix}1/4,3/4,-v/2\\ (v+1)/2,(1-v)/2,-v/2,-v/2,v/2 \end{matrix}\right.\right).
> $$

Thanks.

Comment: You can reduce that formula to an identity involving hypergeometric functions by the same method as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2893177). The G-function becomes a sum of two ${_2F_3}$ functions.